# Spectrum of a strongly regular graph with a vertex deleted

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, characteristic-polynomial

I want to know if it is possible to calculate the characteristic polynomial of a strongly regular graph denoted $SRG(n,k,\lambda,\mu)$ when one or two of its vertices are deleted. I have found some relations to walk generating functions based on Godsil's textbook on Algebraic Combinatorics, but not sure how to do the calculations. Along the same lines, is it possible to extend the approach to distance regular graphs?